# Postgresql join table

Tags: postgresql

Fist table:

```
Value Time
4     2014.12.2 14:00:00
5     2014.12.2 14:01:00
7     2014.12.2 14:02:00
4     2014.12.2 14:03:00
```

second table:

```
Value Time
10    2014.12.2 14:00:00
5     2014.12.2 14:01:00
3     2014.12.2 14:03:00
12    2014.12.2 14:05:00
```

how to do so:

```
Value, Value2 Time
4      10     2014.12.2 14:00:00
5      5      2014.12.2 14:01:00
7      3      2014.12.2 14:02:00
4      -      2014.12.2 14:03:00
-      12     2014.12.2 14:05:00
```

I have implemented the code:

```
SELECT t1.value as Value,
                t2.value as Value2,
                COALESCE(t1.Time, t2.Time) AS Time
           FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 USING (Time)
```

It so:

```
Value, Value2 Time
-      20     2014.12.4 2:25:58
20     -      2014.12.4 2:25:58
20    212     2014.12.4 2:26:09
-     212     2014.12.4 2:26:19
-      12     2014.12.4 2:26:20
```

how to do so here:

```
Value, Value2 Time
20    20      2014.12.4 2:25:58
20    212     2014.12.4 2:25:09
-     212     2014.12.4 2:26:19
-     12      2014.12.4 2:26:20
```

Comment: You need to provide a minimum of explanation. And table definitions (`\d tbl` in psql). The exact data type is essential to establish "equality".

Answer (score 1):

As simple as

```
         SELECT t1.value as Value,
                t2.value as Value2,
                COALESCE(t1.Time, t2.Time) AS Time
           FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 USING (Time)
```

References:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join

Comment: That'S Perfect! And if more than 2 tables

Comment: @Антон Паклин: then just put more joins (and please check the provided links)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.value,
   t2.value Value2,
   Coalesce(t1.time, t2.time) 
From t1
Full outer join t2
   On t1.time = t2.time
```

Comment: Edited, I'm answering from my phone